# Setting up production and development database for Firebase + Next.js + Vercel

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, vercel

We use Firestore for our DB and use Vercel's Next.js hosting. We wanted a completely isolated development / production DBs, so we set up two separate projects on Firebase, and this gave us two different API keys for each of the projects.

What is the best way to switch between the two configs depending on the Vercel's production / preview / development settings (perhaps based on `NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV`)?

We tried creating two different .json files containing the configs, and switching based on the `NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV`  environment variable, but this seems to yield an `undefined` value for the environment variable on the client rendered pages in my local development build.

```
const firebaseDevConfig = await import("./configs/dev-config.json");
const firebaseProdConfig = await import("./configs/prod-config.json");

const firebaseConfig =
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV === "production"
    ? firebaseProdConfig
    : firebaseDevConfig;
```

Update: It seems that the `NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV` returns the expected value `"preview"` in the deployed preview version. How do I get it to return "development" in my local dev build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around this issue by storing the development config as a string in the `.env` file and also setting up the production environment variable through Vercel's dashboard.

The final code looked something like this:

```
export const firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_CONFIG!
);
```

where `NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_CONFIG` is the name of the environment variable containing the dev/prod Firebase configs as a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using .local.env file or just .env? Also, I recommend setting up the firebase CLI and emulators see --> https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite

Comment: I'm using `.env`. Should I be saving it as `.env.local` instead? Also, we are using Firebase as database only, and using Vercel hosting.

Comment: yes, because that is where it pulls it from.